# ¿como cambiar texto de textview con interface android?

Tags: java, android, interface

cuando recibo un evento de mensaje, se ejecuta el metodo mostrarMensaje, y me muestra en el Toast,pero 
cuando quiero mostrarlo en el texView, me sale error, que parametro nesecita o como puedo asiganrlo el valor.

```
public class RegistroPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity implements MyReceiver.Listener{
 private EditText etDato;
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         etDato = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDato);
        }


  @Override
    public void mostrarMensaje(Context con,String mensaje) {
     // etDato.setText(mensaje);  me sale error   --------------------------------->error
        Toast.makeText(con, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
    }
```

si al Toast, no le paso el context tambien me sale el mismo error.
//el error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start receiver pe.pro.jhon.ubeprivado.util.MyReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException:
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Cual es el archivo .xml que contiene el EditText? debes usar setContentView(id layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta especificar el método `setContentView()` en donde defines el layout que debe contener el `EditText` con id `etDato`, por ejemplo si tu layout es /res/layout/main_activity.xml, puedes definirlo de esta forma:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity); //*Agregar
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

}
```